# Why do I need to use \bibliographystyle twice?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm working on a fairly vanilla (few additional packages), up-to-date installation of MiKTeX 2.9.6668 on Windows. At some point, I noticed that my source file includes two instances of the `\bibliographystyle{...}` command. It's called once in the preamble, and once in the document body right before generating the actual bibliography using `\bibliography{...}`.

After removing the first of the two calls, `bibtex` no longer generated a `.bbl` file, so the bibliography was missing from my document. Then, I found out that removing the other call *also* makes the bibliography no longer compile. The document will only contain the bibliography if *both* calls are present in the document, which seems redundant to me. In examples on where to use `\bibliographystyle`, I have seen both options, but none of the sources I could find says that it needs to be present in both places.

I did use `makebst` of the `custom-bib` package to generate a custon `bericht.bst` bibliography style. This style works fine and my bibliography looks as I expect it to, and it doesn't make a difference whether I use the custom style or `plain` – the command still has to be there both times for the bibliography to appear.

My toolchain is running `latex` -> `bibtex` -> `latex` -> `latex`, and I'm using a standard BibTeX `.bib` file (no `biblatex`). The `bibtex` logfile (`.blg`) contains the following:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: bericht.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file bericht.aux
(There was 1 error message)
```

This error message is the same, regardless of which instance of `\bibliographystyle` I remove.

The issue is not critical since everything works as I want it to as long as both calls are there. But why is that so?

**Edit:** It turns out that I didn't go far enough in narrowing down the problem. The cause is, of course, that I misunderstood and misapplied a command offered by a package, and that I was stupidly very confident that that one couldn't be related to the problem. Here is a reduced source that causes the issue; I will post the answer right after.

```
% !TX TS-program = pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt,hidelinks]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{draft}
\toggletrue{draft}

\title{Article title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\nocite{*}

\iftoggle{draft}{%
    \listoftodos
}
% Commenting this out causes bibtex failure.
% \bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bericht}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site, please post a full minimal example so we can get a better idea of what exactly you are doing, there are many factors and without code we have no idea.

Comment: You answered your own question in the first paragraph. One of the commands in `\bibliographystyle`, the other one is `\bibliography`. They are not the same command.

Comment: @thymaro: No, I use `\bibliographystyle` twice, and `\bibliography` once. If I remove one of the two calls to `\bibliographystyle`, `bibtex`fails.
I will prepare a minimal example that causes the issue and add it to the question.

Comment: Denn bruche mr es MWE.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I misapplied a feature by the `etoolbox` package, which I prematurely excluded as a possible cause (partly because it "seemed to work").

The offending code is the `\iftoggle` which is lacking an 'else' block.

```
\iftoggle{draft}{%
    \listoftodos
}
```

This does not work properly without an additional group (even if empty) to denote the output if the toggle is false. The `\iftoggle` immediately preceded the bibliography in my document, and caused the error. It was enough to add an empty group to the toggle:

```
\iftoggle{draft}{%
    \listoftodos
}{}
```

`bibtex` now properly works with only one of the calls to `\bibliographystyle`, and complains if both are in the source:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6700 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: minimal.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 21 of file minimal.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {plain}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
```

What led to the confusion (not an excuse for wrongfully excluding it as a potential cause, I know!) was that the document was generated properly even with the missing group, as long as the `\bibliographystyle` was repeated before calling `\bibliography`. I'm still not entirely sure why it needed to also be called *before* the `\iftoggle` to produce a correct-looking output. But that's what you get for only skimming package documentation. Mea culpa.

Comment: Since `\iftoggle` expects three arguments, the missing last arg ate `\bibliographystyle` and `bericht` should appear in the text.

Comment: That makes sense, and is exactly what happens, thank you! The name of the bibliography style appears in the document, well-hidden at the end of the `\listoftodos`.

Comment: That's often why I insert a `\clearpage` or simular before these notes.